# How to query for "where data does not exist" in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, where-clause

I am trying to make a query which says something like if hire_status exist, do not print out those value instead only print out those with hire_status that doesn't have value yet. But I do not know how to do it. I did something like that for now, can someone help me? Is another kind of function to do it?

What I want to do is inside the view file, when the user has inserted his data into the database, their name should disappear inside the view file to avoid clicking the person name twice. But I do not know how to do that

Here is the code:

```
     public function getHire(){
        $data['data'] = DB::table('personal_infos')->join('hires', 'personal_infos.id', '=', 'hires.user_id')->select('personal_infos.id','personal_infos.Name','personal_infos.deleted_at','hires.hire_status')->where('deleted_at',NULL)->whereNull('hires.hire_status')->get()->sortByDesc('created_at');
       if(count($data)>0){
        return view('hire',$data);
    }else{
    return view('hire');
}
```

personal_info models:

```
class personal_info extends Eloquent
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $fillable = array('Email', 'Name');
    protected $table = 'personal_infos';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
public function hires() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\hire','user_id');
    }
}
```

hire model:

```
   protected $fillable = array('hire_status','user_id');

public function personal_infos() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\personal_info', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

hire.blade.php

```
   <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th><strong><big>Name: </big></strong></th>     
        <th><strong><big>Hire Action: </big></strong></th>  
      </tr>
      <td>
      <tr>
        @foreach($data as $value)
      <tr>    
      <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->id])}}">{{$value->Name}}</a></th>
    <th> 
      <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/hire_status/'.$value->id) }}">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
         <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{$value->id}}">
        <input type="radio" name="hire_status" value="Yes"> Yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="hire_status" value="No"> No<br> 

         <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>  
   </th>             
      </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Create Eloquent models for your data and define relations - it will be much easier then to get data you need without writing joins manually. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo, i have already defined the relationship already but i do not know how to use it

Comment: I want to print out personal_infos, column name if table hires, is empty, this is the part that i do not know how to do

Comment: I'm talking about defining relations in your Eloquent models, not in the database. If you have models already, paste them in your question.

Comment: BTW, what's wrong with your code? If you don't want to use Eloquent models then unfortunately building a query like you do is a way to go.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo i have edited the question, the code that i put inside my getHire function is just a guess, i am not sure how to do it properly. I saw people use isEmpty() function, can it work for this scenario?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158032/discussion-between-jedrzej-kurylo-and-dkna).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Eloquent models and relations between them properly defined, you'll be able to fetch all objects of ** personal_info** class that do not have a related **hire** record with:

```
$personalInfos = personal_info::whereDoesntHave('hires')->get();
```